# Is the .bt Octomap preserving the coordinates of the ROS environment it has been built from?

Tags: ros, octomap, ros-kinetic, coordinate

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think the title is self-explicative.
I constructed an Octomap out of a robot moving in a simulated environment. In that environment, the coordinate (x1, y1, z1) with respect to the world frame was occupied by an obstacle.
If I check the node (x1, y1, z1) of the created Octomap, will it be occupied, and if so, by the same obstacle? Or will the Octomap have assigned new coordinates based on the .bt file created?

Also, will it happen the same when the octomap is not in a .bt file and it is being updated continuously?

Thank you. This was also posted on Octomap's GitHub, so I will copy the answer given in one site to the other.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/285857/is-the-.bt-octomap-preserving-the-coordinates-of-the-ros-environment-it-has-been-built-from?/) by [thepirate16](https://answers.ros.org/users/26128/thepirate16/) on ROS Answers with karma: 101 on 2018-03-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As answered in Octomap's GitHub by @AHornung: https://github.com/OctoMap/octomap/issues/204

*"The .bt format does not compute or change any coordinate transformations, an OctoMap is aways regarded in the same frame. So unless you manually apply a transformation in ROS on top, the coordinates should be the same."*

---

Originally posted by [thepirate16](https://answers.ros.org/users/26128/thepirate16/) with karma: 101 on 2018-03-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0